# Solidity constructor syntax

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

Looking through an OpenZeppelin tutorial, I came across this code snippet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract GameItem {
    constructor() ERC721("GameItem", "ITM") {}
```

What is the syntax in the constructor that allows a class instance to be passed in after constructor()? I can’t seem to find any reference to this in the Solidity docs

Comment: Can you add more details about your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's invoking a parent constructor, in this case the parent class is named `ERC721`. It's the same as calling `super.constructor()` or `parent.constructor()` in some other languages.

In order to call the parent constructor, your contract needs to actually inherit from it:

```
contract GameItem is ERC721 {
```

---

Solidity supports inheritance from multiple parents. That's why you cannot just use an ambiguous keyword such as `parent`. By explicitly stating the parent class name, you can specify which values you want to pass to which parent:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Parent1 {
    constructor(string memory message1) {}
}

contract Parent2 {
    constructor(string memory message2) {}
}

contract Child is Parent1, Parent2 {
    constructor() Parent1("hello") Parent2("world") {}
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors